# Getting error while installing the Angular4 cli

Tags: node.js, angular

I am getting the following error while installing the Angular 4 cli.

Error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
C:\Users\User>node -v
v8.9.4
C:\Users\User>npm -v
3.3.8
C:\Users\User>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\R
oaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v8.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.8
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'internal/util/types'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\npm-debug.log
C:\Users\User>
```

I have installed the Node version 8.9.4 in my Windows 7 machine and while installing this I am getting this error.

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1124)

Comment: I have also refereed this site but there are so many different solution so its confusing.

Comment: Hi Satya. Reminder on posting tips: (1) try to respect case conventions where you can, for readability; (2) there's no need to add please-halp-me to _all_ of your questions - readers don't want to see you beg and plead; (3) the quote device is for quotes, not a general heading device.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade npm module

> npm i -g npm

else =>  its better to use v6

install nvm [node version manager]

```
nvm install v6.11.4
nvm use v6.11.4 
nvm default v6.11.4
npm i -g npm
```

then install

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: whats the current version of npm ?

Comment: I have also uninstalled and installed again the node.js but same npm version is coming.

Comment: Is not it possible to run with this node version or How can I upgrade the npm version ?

Comment: my version is 5.6.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165776/discussion-between-satya-and-rijin).

Comment: finally check for permissions run terminal with Admin privillage

Answer (score 0):

try clearing npm by 
npm cache clean --force 
and install it.